# Comunicazione NDEF

Tags: nfc, p2p, ndef, nfc-p2p

I'm working on a mobile app and my intent is to make the Arduino communicate with the smartphone. so far I can only read the first message sent by the arduino, when the application is not active.

I'm using this function of react-native-nfc-manager library:

```
getLaunchTagEvent ()
```

After this event I can no longer read other NDEF messages. how can i solve?

The code is as follows:

```
componentDidMount(){
  NfcManager.isSupported()
        .then(supported => {
            this.setState({ supported });
            if (supported) {
                this._startNfc();
            }
        })
}
 
_startNfc() {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      NfcManager.getLaunchTagEvent()
          .then(tag => {
              console.log('launch tag', tag);
              if (tag) {
                  this.setState({ tag });
              }
          })
          .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
          })
      
      
    }
  }
```

Also i am trying to read the tag with the application open, but the action fails on the arduino. solutions?
The code is as follows:

```
readData = async () => {
    NfcManager.registerTagEvent(
     tag => {
         console.log('Tag Discovered', tag);
     },
     'Hold your device over the tag',
     {
      readerModeFlags:
      NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A | NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK,
      readerModeDelay: 2,
   },
 );

}
```

The Arduino code is as follows:

```
#include "SPI.h"
#include "PN532_SPI.h"
#include "snep.h"
#include "NdefMessage.h"

PN532_SPI pn532spi(SPI, 10);
SNEP nfc(pn532spi);
uint8_t ndefBuf[128];

void setup() {
     Serial.begin(9600);
     Serial.println("NFC Peer to Peer-Send Message");
}

void loop() {
     Serial.println("Send a message to Peer");

     NdefMessage message = NdefMessage();
     message.addTextRecord("Hello");
    
int messageSize = message.getEncodedSize();
if (messageSize > sizeof(ndefBuf)) {
    Serial.println("ndefBuf is too small");
    while (1) {
    }
}

message.encode(ndefBuf);
if (0 >= nfc.write(ndefBuf, messageSize)) {
    Serial.println("Failed");
} else {
    Serial.println("Success");
}

delay(3000); 
}
```

Comment: You need to show your Arduino code and Arduino hardware details as well as this is probably caused by an interaction of the 2 codebases

Comment: I add the code used on Arduino

Answer (score 0):

The uses of `SNEP` (and LLCP) complicates things as this is a peer to peer protocol and peer to peer has been deprecated in Android 10 and not supported in iOS and I'm not so familiar with it.

I'm not sure it is possible read `SNEP` messages using `enableReaderMode` (this is what you have asked react-native-nfc-manager library to use).
This is because `SNEP` and (LLCP) is not a `TYPE A` technology type

If you look at the NFC standards diagram at https://pdfslide.net/documents/divnfc0804-250-nfc-standards-v18.html

It might be a `TYPE F` technology type so I would try instead of `NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A` I would use `NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_F` or enable all of the technologies to be on the safe side (though I think this might not work as well)

But if this does not work, normally with Android Peer to Peer it expects only to be sent `NDEF` messages and you have disabled the System NFC App from processing NDEF messages with `NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK` so I would try removing that and work with the `Ndef` tag technology type.

But I don't think any of that will help, the next thing I would try is to not use `enableReaderMode` with `react-native-nfc-manager` but use the underlying `enableForgroundDispatch` methods by just by specifying `NfcManager.registerTagEvent();`.
As this interacts with the Android System NFC App at a later point in the chain of events where the Android System NFC App is creating `Intents` to share with other Apps either to Launch an App to handle the `Intent` or pass it to a running App that has asked to be sent NFC `Intents`.
As this looks to be a common point between how the Android System NFC App handles real NFC Tags and Peer to Peer `SNEP` messages as a `SNEP` message can launch your App.

But going forward I would not use `SNEP` (peer to peer) as this is deprecated but get the Arduino to do Host Card Emulation to send the data (Then you could use Reader Mode)